# sort and count the value in db

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

## this is my db(salelist)

id     type        firstname     mob     affid      salestatus

1      refund     nike              ****      5443     cancelled

2      sale         bob              ****      5443     ok

3      sale         mike            ****      5123     ok

4      sale         john              ****      5443     ok

5      refund     cat                ****      5443     cancelled

6      sale         mony            ****      5443     ok

7      refund     ity                  ****      5123     cancelled

i want to sort and count how many sale and refund get to each affiliate
i want result like this in a table

affid        sale           refund
5443       3               2
5123       1               1
please help to find out

this is my code
[mycode](http://thebusinesscoach.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/code-1.jpg)

i got this error while running
mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\SANN\check\affiliateslist.php on line 23

Answer (score 1):

You could use conditional `case` expressions to count the relevant sale types:

```
SELECT   affid,
         COUNT (CASE type WHEN 'sale' THEN 1 END) AS sale,
         COUNT (CASE type WHEN 'refund' THEN 1 END) AS refund
FROM     salelist
GROUP BY affid
```

Comment: i got this error mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\SANN\check\affiliateslist.php on line 23

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT affid, 
SUM(case when `type` = 'sale' then 1 else 0 end) sale,
SUM(case when `type` = 'refund' then 1 else 0 end) refund
FROM salelist
GROUP BY affid
```